# build own cache, in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, caching

I have a list with four elements: `created_at`, `text`, `name`, `screen_name`. The first represent a date of creation, the second the texto of a tweet and the latest the name and screen name of user.
I want to storage this information with lifespan, a random lifespan. For this i thinking using the cache and the implementation of this link https://medium.com/@kezhenxu94/how-to-build-your-own-cache-in-kotlin-1b0e86005591.

My questions is:

- use a map key-value and save in value a string with all information (`created_at`, `text`, `name`, `screen_name`)?
- how add this information in map with this code?

Please, give me a sample example for storage this data. Or if there is another way to make what i want more correctly, tell me.

My code in the moment:

```
class ExpirableCache(private val delegate: Cache, private val flushInterval: Long = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1000)) : Cache {
    private val dataTweet: Map<Long, Long>? = null

    private var lastFlushTime = System.nanoTime()

    override val size: Int
        get() = delegate.size

    override fun set(key: Any, value: Any) {
        delegate[key] = value
    }

    override fun remove(key: Any): Any? {
        recycle()
        return delegate.remove(key)
    }

    override fun get(key: Any): Any? {
        recycle()
        return delegate[key]
    }

    override fun add(key: Any, value: Any) {
        dataTweet[0, value]
    }

    override fun clear() = delegate.clear()

    private fun recycle() {
        val shouldRecycle = System.nanoTime() - lastFlushTime >= TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(flushInterval)
        if (!shouldRecycle) return
        delegate.clear()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this belongs more into code-review section - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/